# com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField does not exist

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I'm using scene builder to create an user interface which uses `com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField`. It works properly in the Scene Builder and it's preview.

[image]

But in the NetBeans editor I get the class does not exist error.

[image]

When I try to run the application, I get the following runtime error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadTypeForPackage(FXMLLoader.java:2916)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadType(FXMLLoader.java:2905)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.importClass(FXMLLoader.java:2846)
    ... 60 more
```

I used the [Library manager](http://docs.gluonhq.com/scenebuilder/#_library_manager) in Scene Builder to install `com.gluonhq:charm` repository. But I still get those errors. Any suggestion will be highly appreciated.

Comment: import the external `jar` into the Netbeans Project.

Comment: I searched online, I couldn't find the JAR file.

Comment: All the gluonhq releases can be found under http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/. You would want to use the [charm-glisten](http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/) jars.

Comment: @ItachiUchiha,I'm trying to use pom.xml here and I don't seem to find charm-glisten in mavven repositories, only other charms that do not have the controls in them. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @Laura http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/4.4.1/

Answer (score 3):

you can download the repo from:
http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/4.4.1/

If you add this as a library in your JavaFX application and reference it with an import in the FXMLDocumentController:

```
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressBar; 
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField;
```

And ofcourse the link to the FXML file:

```
@FXML
private ProgressIndicator progress;
@FXML
private ProgressBar progressbar;
@FXML
private TextField textfield;
```

in the FXML file:

```
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressBar?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ProgressIndicator?>
<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.TextField?>
```

and do not forget to set the fx:id:

```
<ProgressIndicator fx:id="progress" layoutX="85.0" layoutY="14.0" opacity="0.75" prefHeight="132.0" prefWidth="137.0" progress="0.25" radius="75.0" />
<ProgressBar fx:id="progressbar" layoutX="16.0" layoutY="177.0" opacity="0.75" prefHeight="18.0" prefWidth="288.0" progress="0.75" />
<TextField fx:id="textfield" layoutX="118.0" layoutY="80.0" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="92.0" />
```

It should work (works fine with me =^)

see for more info:

http://docs.gluonhq.com/charm/javadoc/4.3.5/index.html?com/gluonhq/charm/glisten/control/TextField.html

Answer (score 0):

This `TextField` is a product of Gluon which needs the external library. It will cause such exceptions, if you do not intend to use.

[image]

The control below is builtin `TextField`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

head over to [GluonHQ](http://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/4.4.1/)
and download charm.glisten....jar and import it in your libraries of the Javafx package in netbeans.. it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Just download charm-glisten JAR file here:https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/

go to the latest version

for exemple:

> charm-glisten-6.0.2.jar

in 6.0.2 version under https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/6.0.2/

Answer (score 0):

Try to add scenebuilder-xxx-all.jar to libraries of your project (it works for me). In windows you find it in the setup former in C, but in Linux you have to search for it :

[image]