# How to use ControlsFX with javafx and FXML?

Tags: javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

I'm new to Javafx and FXML and trying to import ControlsFX in scene builder and when I try to Run the java application it throws java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

[image]
My Graphic Class is as follows, 
I have not imported ControlsFX in java class file.

```
        FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("homeUI.fxml"));
        Parent root_ = loader.load();
        primaryStage.initStyle(StageStyle.UNDECORATED);
        Scene main_scene = new Scene(root_);
        primaryStage.setScene(main_scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

My FXML file is as follows

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>

<BorderPane maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" style="-fx-background-color: rgb(66,64,61);" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/11.0.1" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <top>
      <Icon content="HELP_OUTLINE" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
   </top>
</BorderPane>
```

I have imported this Icon from ControlsFX via Scene Builder.

Comment: The `Icon` class is not part of the ControlsFX API but part of the Gluon Mobile API. Furthermore this is a exception at runtime, nothing happening at compile time.

Comment: Do you have Gradle and Android SDK installed? I think you are mixing the things here... you want to use controlsfx but you are using Gluon HQ Charm as stated in your fxml file... <?import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.Icon?>

Comment: from @fabian and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43760039/com-gluonhq-charm-glisten-control-textfield-does-not-exist I have got it.